# Visual Studio 2022 does not have Add/Docker Support

Tags: docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2022

Do you need Docker Desktop installed for the VS 2022 Add/Docker Support menu to appear in the project's right click dropdown menu? In my VS2022 that menu is no where to be found but it's there on another machine where Docker Desktop is installed. Is it true that you have to have Docker Desktop installed, otherwise you will not have Add/Docker Support menu in your VS 2022? or there is something else I am missing here? We do not want to install Docker Desktop on this machine, but want to use Docker-compose through WSL instead.